# Why did Deadpool call Colossus "dad"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In *Deadpool* (2016), when Deadpool hit Colossus for the first time he got a huge Newtonian reaction force in return. He then tried to feel Colossus' body without looking at him and said "Dad?"

It was quite funny, but we later learned that Deadpool was born a normal human and Colossus just wanted to recruit him to Xavier's mutant club. Then, why did he expect a hard-skin strong man to be his dad?

Comment: I don't think he _did_ expect him to be his dad. I think he was joking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He didn't expect it to be his dad, it's a joke. Deadpool had just punched Colossus in his "girder" and then feels it, it's a joke about having an abusive father i.e. he feels his girder, "recognises it" and so makes the joke. The scene is below.

Comment: A similar thing happens in the too